# Registering extern function with clang's JIT?

Tags: compiler-construction, jit, llvm, clang

Im trying to register an extern function with clangs JIT without success.

Heres the function im trying to call:

```
extern "C"
int myFunction(int val)
{
 fprintf(stderr, "success!");

 return 1;
}
```

Heres the code im using to register it:

```
llvm::FunctionType* ft = llvm::FunctionType::get(llvm::Type::getInt32Ty(llvm::getGlobalContext()),
  std::vector<const llvm::Type*>(1, llvm::Type::getInt32Ty(llvm::getGlobalContext())), false);

llvm::Function* F = llvm::Function::Create(ft, llvm::Function::ExternalLinkage, "yipee", Mod);
EE->addGlobalMapping(F, (void*)(intptr_t)yipee);
```

And heres the c code which will be ran by the JIT:

```
int myFunction(int);
int main()
{
   int dd = myFunction(5);

    return 0;
}
```

My code is not right or something else? Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: What is the error? What is a full command line of starting llvm?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure to link the external function into the same program that the JIT is being called from.